# Is bijective continuous image of a nowhere dense subset nowhere dense or not?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Suppose that $f : X \longrightarrow Y$ is a continuous bijective map where $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces. Let $A \subset X$ be nowhere dense in $X$. Then is it a true fact that $f(A)$ is nowhere dense in $Y$?

If it is true then how can I prove it? Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are $X$ and $Y$ ? Metric spaces ?

Comment: No they are topological spaces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not true. Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space with $\tau\neq\{\emptyset,X\}$. Let $A\subset X$ be a nowehere dense non-empty subset. Let $Y=\bigl(X,\{\emptyset,X\}\bigr)$ and let $f\colon X\longrightarrow Y$ be the identity function. Then $\overline{f(A)}=Y$ and therefore $f(A)$ isn't nowere dense.

Comment: @Jose would you please make it clear that what do you mean by $Y=\bigl(X,\{\emptyset,X\}\bigr)$? Then it will help me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @ArnabChatterjee. $Y$ is the topological space which, as a set, is $X$ and whose topology is $\{\emptyset,X\}$ (the trivial or indiscrete topology).

Answer (score 6):

Here is a counterexample with metric spaces.

Let $\mathbb R$ be the real line with the usual metric.

Let $\mathbb Q=\{r_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ be the set of all rational numbers.

Let $A=\{(x,0):x\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q\}.$

Let $M=A\cup\{(r_n,\frac1n):n\in\mathbb N\}\subset\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ with the Euclidean metric.

The projection map $f(x,y)=x$ is a continuous bijection from $M$ to $\mathbb R.$

$A$ is a closed nowhere dense subset of $M,$ while $f(A)=\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ is a dense subset of $\mathbb R.$